# Setting up ansible-pull targeting web and database servers with different environments

Tags: ansible

I'm working on setting up ansible-pull for both a web server and a database server. These servers need to be configured for different environments - specifically, development, staging, and production. Each environment has distinct variables like port numbers and other configurations.

How should I structure my Ansible playbook and variables in this scenario to accommodate the different environments while targeting localhost?

Typically, I'd use an inventory file to group these environments by their respective IP addresses and then leverage group variables. However, in this case, ansible-pull is targeting only localhost.

Comment: Use your inventory as usual. Have your playbook target whatever group is the relevant one. Run ansible pull with a limit on the current server. Since the connection parameter by default is "smart" it should use a local connection to the current server.